# How can we restrict git to not allow merge from the feature branch if it is some commits behind the destination branch

Tags: git

How to restrict git, to not allow merge in the merge requests from the local/feature branch to the  project designated branch like "develop" or "master" if the local/feature branch is some commits behind the designated branches ("develop/ master")?

Detailed explanation

branch1 : develop (present upto date branch)
developer 1 create the feature branch (feature1) from the develop and work on it
developer 2 has created the feature branch(feature2) from the develop and works on it.
Now developer 2 and developer 1 both have submitted the merge request to the review
When reviewer merged developer 1 merge request develop is udpated with the code of feature 1 branch.
Now when reviewer goes to developer 2 merge request, he will see that the feature 2 is some commits behind as developer 2 has not rebased his branch with develop. So in such case I want the Merge option to be disabled untill developer 2 rebase his branch

Comment: Your question doesn't make a whole lot of sense. On one hand, you can't restrict any local git operations. On other hand, you might be able to restrict pushing to designated server (e.g. GitHub, Gerrit, gitlab, etc) if you do it right.

Comment: I want to allow merge only by the reviewer when feature branch is properly rebased with the destination branches (no commits left), otherwise there would be some changes which may get dropped which were merged to develop by other feature branches

Comment: Have you explored git hooks ? You can create a pre push hook

Comment: Not yet, I am checking it now

Comment: Git hooks won't help. You need to setup proper code review process, using one of common methods: GitHub (paid), Gitlab (paid if hosted), Gerrit (free, need local server setup).

Answer (score 0):

Note that it is impossible to restrict any local git operations, due to git distributed nature.

You can only restrict pushing commits to central server, or at least make those commits go through review process before allowing to be pushed.

For that, you need to setup proper code review process, using one of common methods: [GitHub](https://GitHub.com) (paid), [Gitlab](https://gitlab.com) (paid if hosted) or [Gerrit](http://gerritcodereview.com) (free, need local server setup).